# Parsing nested XML using XMLin

Tags: xml, perl, parsing, nested

I spent a couple of hours trying to figure out how to make sense of this nested XML using XMLin but with no luck. I also tried the examples on this site; how can I get passed lca-data and iterate over prefix?

Dumper output is here:  http://pastebin.com/a4N8AtX1

Simple code:

```
$url = "http://www.localcallingguide.com/xmllocalprefix.php?npa=514&nxx=307";
$xml = new XML::Simple;
$data = $xml->XMLin(&getURL($url), ForceArray => [qw( lca-data prefix )]);

print Dumper( $data );

foreach $e (@{$data->{prefix}}) {
  print STDERR $e->{npa} . "\n";
}
```

No output comes out of it...

Thanks a mil in advance

Comment: There is no `$data->{prefix}` -- you probably want that to be `$data->{lca-data}[0]{prefix}` in your `foreach`.

Comment: It does make sense but it doesn't get into the loop that way either

Comment: Whoops; the hyphen isn't a valid identifier character, so you have to use quotes: `$data->{'lca-data'}[0]{prefix}`.  `use warnings; use strict;` would likely help.

Comment: Hurray :) Thanks !!  it works well with the quotes:  `$data->{'lca-data'}[0]{'prefix'}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First - really - read the manpage for [`XML::Simple`](http://search.cpan.org/~grantm/XML-Simple-2.20/lib/XML/Simple.pm). Especially pay attention to the bit that says:

> The use of this module in new code is discouraged. Other modules are available which provide more straightforward and consistent interfaces.

Also - don't use `&` in front of subroutine calls - they're a bad idea in general - there's some very specific reasons to use them, and that isn't one.

And you should *always* use `strict` and `warnings` especially when posting code for someone else to look at.

Given your task seems to be outputting each `npa` element to `STDERR` I would suggest you could approach it like this instead - using [`XML::Twig`](http://search.cpan.org/~mirod/XML-Twig-3.49/Twig.pm) instead of `XML::Simple`

```
#!/usr/bin/local/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

use LWP::Simple;
use XML::Twig;

my $url =
    'http://www.localcallingguide.com/xmllocalprefix.php?npa=514&nxx=307';

my $twig = XML::Twig->new(
    'twig_handlers' => {
        'npa' => sub { print STDERR $_->text, "\n"; }
    }
);
$twig->parse( get($url) );
```

Which sets a handler to 'trigger' on each `npa` subelement and print it - it does this as your XML is being parsed, which means you can do some quite neat tricks like modifying it as you're parsing (e.g. deleting or moving elements around).

If you're looking to simply iterate on an element, then you can either do it that way - which has a nice advantage of not using lots of memory, as XML *can*. (XML::Twig has `purge` which lets you discard any processed XML).

Otherwise, there's the 'children' or 'get_xpath' options:

```
my $twig = XML::Twig->new()->parse( get($url) );
foreach
    my $prefix ( $twig->root->first_child('lca-data')->children('prefix') )
{
    print $prefix ->first_child_text('npa'), "\n";
}

### alternatively:

foreach my $prefix ( $twig->root->get_xpath('./lca-data/prefix') ) {
    print $prefix ->first_child_text('npa'), "\n";
}
```

If you wanted to use a subroutine to process and purge you could do this:

```
sub process_prefix {
    my ( $twig, $prefix ) = @_;
    print $prefix ->first_child_text('npa'), "\n";
    $twig->purge;    #clears already parsed data - good if your XML is large!
}

my $url =
    'http://www.localcallingguide.com/xmllocalprefix.php?npa=514&nxx=307';

my $twig =
    XML::Twig->new( 'twig_handlers' => { 'prefix' => \&process_prefix } )
    ->parse( get($url) );
```

Well done on using a parser for XML parsing. But take a look at `XML::Twig` or `XML::LibXML` instead of `XML::Simple` - they're both much better tools for the job. ([`XML::Twig`](http://search.cpan.org/~mirod/XML-Twig-3.49/Twig.pm#Simplifying_XML_processing) even has the `simpify` method which ... pretty much replicates `XML::Simple` if you really need it for backwards compatibility)

But the solution to your question as asked is:

```
foreach $e (@{ $data->{'lca-data'}[0]{'prefix'} } {
```

Comment: Jim already had given the answer but thanks for all the details and for the Twig reference, I will surely take a look at it. Cheers